# How to check if something is a file using GetFileAttributes() on windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'd like to test if a file system object is a file using the GetFileAttributes() function on windows. [I've read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117(v=vs.85).aspx), and it seems that this is not so easy, as there does not seem to be a single flag that tells me that "this is a file". So what I currently do is  something like this:

```
int is_file = 0;
DWORD attr = GetFileAttributes(path);
if (attr != 0xFFFFFFFF) {
  DWORD DontWantAttrs = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT | 0xFFFFC000;
  is_file = ( attr & DontWantAttrs ) == 0;
}
```

This seems to give me the correct results on my tests so far, but I am not sure whether this is totally correct, i.e. whether it will return true for everything that is a file, and false for everything that is not a file.

Comment: Why not accept `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE`?

Comment: I need the files' data available, so -in this case - having it offline is not helping me. However, in a more general case I agree it should probably be accepted.

Comment: Consider FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT. It can be a pointer to a file or directory, or it can be a file symlink. Do you want to consider this to be a file, or do you want to check what it points to?

Comment: If the requested path does not include the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` flag than by definition it must be a file, so there is no point in checking the other flags. However, if `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` is present, the path is for the link itself, not the file/directory that is being linked to. `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` will still tell you whether the link is for a directory or a file. If you want to check if a linked file exists, you have to open the link using `CreateFile()`.

Comment: FYI, `0xFFFFC000` is `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_INTEGRITY_STREAM | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NO_SCRUB_DATA | 0xFFFC0000` (`0xFFFC0000` does not include any defined attributes at this time, but that may change in the future).

Comment: Remy, what about FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE? I would assume that an FS object with this flag is not a file, either. As for FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT, I see that as something like a symlink, so not a file by itself.

Comment: I have never encountered `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE`, but it exists to identify file handles to devices opened using paths like `\\.\PhysicalDrive<Index>` or `\\.\<DriveLetter>:` .  You are not likely to see the flag with `GetFileAttributes()`, but with `GetFileInformationByHandle/Ex()`. A symlink in Windows is implemented using a real `.lnk` file. `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` also identifies NTFS hard links and junctions as well (there are additional APIs calls you can make to differentiate what a reparse point actually represents, if needed).

Comment: When parsing a path in the kernel, an object's `ParseProcedure` can return `STATUS_REPARSE` or `STATUS_REPARSE_OBJECT`. In early NT this was used mainly for object / configuration (registry) manager links. NT 5 added NTFS junction reparse points. NT 6 added NTFS symbolic link reparse points, created programmatically via [`CreateSymbolicLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363866) or using cmd's `mklink` command. Hard links have nothing to do with reparse points; they're just another directory entry for the same file. A .lnk file is a shell shortcut, not a filesystem symbolic link.